# Dúvida em objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ao criar uma constante e depois adicioná la como uma propriedade dentro de um objeto, o objeto entende que é dele (ou seja, que é a mesma coisa), porém nesse momento eu terei a const name e o aluno1.name (duas variáveis diferentes). Como isso funciona por baixo? Não consigo entender essa lógica...

```
const aluno1 = {
  nome,
};

console.log(nome); // Pedro
console.log(aluno1.nome); // Pedro

aluno1.nome = "José";

console.log(nome); // Pedro
console.log(aluno1.nome); // José
```

Comment: o nome é variável?

Comment: É uma constante mas poderia ser uma let tb